# Using component method in other component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, components

I'm just learning Angular and I'm having trouble passing a method to another component.
Object Item has Array of documents and I would like to delete document with given id

api / item / {itemId} / deleteDocument / {documentId}. This endpoint comes from springboot backend and delete document from item array from database.
This is it what i have:

item.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemService {

  private serviceUrl = 'api/item/';
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  deleteDocument(itemId: number, documentId: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(this.serviceUrl + itemId +'/deleteDocument/' + documentId).pipe();
  }
```

item-component.ts

Here i would like to delete document from document list in Item.

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  item: ItemElem = new ItemElem();

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.itemService.getById(id).subscribe(p => {
      this.item = p;
    });
    this.itemService.getDocumentList(id).subscribe(docList => {
      this.item.documents = docList;
    });
  }

  onDeleteDocument(document: DocumentListItem) {
    this.itemService.deleteDocument(this.item.id, document.id).subscribe(p => {
          this.item.documents = this.item.documents.filter(
            doc => doc.id !== document.id);
      });
  }
```

document-list-component.ts

```
deleteItem(element) {
   // HERE
  }



private prepareDocumentActions() {
    return [
      {
        name: 'edit',
        makeAction: (elem: DocumentListItem) => {
          window.open(elem.documentOpenUrl);
        }
      {
        name: 'delete',
        makeAction: (elem: DocumentListItem) => {
            this.deleteItem(elem.id);
        }
      },
    ];
  }
```

and html:

```
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around none" >
          <div *ngFor="let action of documentActions">
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="action.makeAction(element)">
              <mat-icon class="md-24">{{action.name}}</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          </div>
```

So, i would like to provide method from item-component.ts to document to  document-list-component.ts there where i have deleteDocument() method. In view i have button which after click will be deleted document from documents array in Item and of course from db.

It is probably a trivial task, but I work in java and sprinboot on a daily basis and I do not know Angular. I will be grateful for any help.

Greetings !!

Comment: In a nutshell, you aren't supposed to do it. I would suggest looking into ngrx or similar packages that implement the redux pattern. If you don't want to, use a service with a behavior subject that will contain the list of document and methods to add/delete/edit. Keep the BS private, and expose the methods and an observable of the BS. And look for smart/presentation component concept too.

Answer (score 1):

So, I presume from your question that `document-list-component.ts` is your parent component and `item-component.ts` is your child component. Now, you open an item from document-list-component.ts and you delete that item from the child component. Finally, you want to remove that item from parent component's collection. 
So, If I am correct that you can use   `public onDelete: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter()` in item-component.ts and subscribe that event from `document-list-component.ts` while, you open the child component.
 To subscribe a method you have write like from where you create that component=>

```
 let itemCompo: ItemComponent =new ItemComponent();
  this.subscription = itemCompo.onDelete.subscribe(num=> this.deleteItem(num));
```

**Note:** You can check how to use EventEmitter in Angular from these 2 links 
1. [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eventemitter-todo?file=app%2Ftodo-list%2Ftodo-list.component.ts)
2. [Link](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)
Please check and let me know.

Comment: Many thanks for your answear, but what if I can’t use ItemComponent = new ItemComponent() because itemComponent has constructor with two parameters. Can I like in java create second empty constructor and do it like you did above in the code?

Comment: Yes, you can I belive and please check those 2 links. I think will help you a lot. Best wishes.